# Spinner: selecting item programatically with an on click listener

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

Let's say I have a spinner that has these items: "A", "B", "C". The spinner displays "unknown" if the user hasn't selected anything yet.

**STEP ONE**, the user might have selected an item in the past. So I load data in the view model and `hasSelectedSomething` observes the `LiveData` (asynchronous call to BE that will update the `LiveData`) in view model:

```
viewModel.itemLiveData.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer { item ->
            hasSelectedSomething = (item != "unknown")
        }
)
```

**STEP TWO** I now set up my spinner. I want the spinner to be selected at "unknown" item if the user hasn't selected anything yet, otherwise I want to have it selected at whatever the user selected before.

```
if(!hasSelectedSomething) {
    spinner.setSelection(itemAdapter.getPosition("unknown"))
} else {
    spinner.setSelection(itemAdapter.getPosition(viewModel.getItemString()))
}
```

**STEP THREE** I implement the `spinner.onItemSelectedListener`:

```
spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {
            val selectedItem = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos) as String

            viewModel.updateItemWithSelection(selectedItem)
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
}
```

**MY PROBLEM** is that `LiveData`'s default value is "unknown" meaning the spinner starts at "unknown", that's intended. Then let's say the user has selected "B" in the past, so I programmatically set the spinner to "B". The problem is that `.setSelection` triggers `onItemSelected` which sets selection to whatever the `pos` is and at that time, the `pos` corresponds to "unknown". So what happens is that `LiveData` goes from "unknown" (default value) to "B" (result from call to BE) to "unknown" (onItemSelected had "unknown" selected so it passes that value to view model) again.

How do I solve this problem? How do I properly set up the spinner so that it handles default value, user selection and previous selection?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have logic in the callback of onItemSelected, and you need to *programmatically* set an item, it's common practice to do:

(pseudo-code)

```
yourCallback = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
  ...
}

spinner.setOnItemSelected(null)
spinner.setValue(...)
spinner.setOnItemSelected(yourCallback)
```

So always remove the callback before forcing the spinner to set a value.

"unknown" should be an item in your options. The Spinner (afaicr) doesn't support "null" (It may have changed since 2016 when I had to use one for the last time), but have the ViewModel spit a value.

Lastly, don't do that "if" in your UI (`if(!hasSelectedSomething) {`) simply have the viewModel spit a value (unknown being a valid one) and have your spinner simply set its value. (remember to remove the callback, set the value, set the callback again to prevent a double call).

You have a ViewModel for a reason, have the UI simply react to the state change by observing the spinner's value.